# Accessing Bitmap of CIImage or CGImage besides CGContextDrawImage

Tags: swift, performance, bitmapdata, ciimage, cgcontextdrawimage

I would like to get the RGB (actually, the image provided has been grey-scaled, so grey-scale information would be sufficient) values of the individual pixels of a CIImage.

I currently have the following code:

```
//
// Conversion of CIImage to CGImage
//
   func convertCIImageToCGImage(inputImage: CIImage) -> CGImage! {
   return CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(inputImage, fromRect:     inputImage.extent)
}


 process(image: CGImage) {

    let img=convertCIImageToCGImage(image)

    // Set image width, height
    width = CGImageGetWidth(img)
    height = CGImageGetHeight(img)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

    // Create the bitmap context (ARGB)
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    // draw the image onto the context
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img)

    let uncasted_data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
    data = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(uncasted_data)

    ...
}
```

I then access the individual Pixels using the data variable. I realise that most of the time of this function is spent in

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img)
```

Is there another way of accessing the bitmap of a CIImage or CGImage?

Comment: A lot of people from a _lot_ of different timezones here. Even "Greetings, human" wouldn't be general enough! :p

Comment: Ha, though shallst not copy and paste and forget to paste the first line... Good morning from Switzerland!